# Vue :src Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

I get an error when trying to get the name of the image,  wonder what `product.images[0]` gives an array , and then `product.images[0]․name` gives an error

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-5" v-if="products">
    <div class="row products">
      <div v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="product.id" class="product col-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="product_image">
           <img :src="product.images[0].image" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="product_info">
          <h4 class="product_title">{{product.name}}</h4>
          <h3 class="product_price">${{product.price}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

.

```
export default {
   data(){
      return {
         name: "Products"
      }
   },
  props:{
     products:Array
  },
  computed:{
     baseUrl(){
       return this.$store.getters.getBaseUrl
     }
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you please share all of your object in products array ?

Comment: The first issue I see is that the image object in the images array does not have a 'name' property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that at least one of the elements in `products` does not have an `images` property. Your screenshot shows only the first element.

You could conditionally render that `<img>` based on whether `product.images` exists:

```html
<div class="product_image" v-if="product.images && product.images.length">
  <img :src="product.images[0].image" alt="">
</div>
```